# Unix - Add string between grep resulted lines

Tags: unix, grep, aix

Any chance someone knows a way ( working on RHEL7 and AIX5 ) to make a script that runs either on /bin/bash or /bin/ksh to search in a text file for 1 or more strings using grep ( or another function ), the results being put in a variable but in that variable to have a string "\\n" placed at the end of each occurance?

For example:

> TextFile1.txt

```
[root@server ~]$ cat TextFile1.txt
aby ORA-3120: unable to xx
sxyy  unable to aa
sxyy ORA-3120: unable to aa
ytxy  unable to bb
y41y  unable to dd
yanby  unable to ff
ytxy ORA-3120: unable to bb
y41y ORA-3120: unable to dd
y124gby  unable to gg
yanby ORA-3120: unable to ff
aby  unable to xx
y124gby ORA-3120: unable to gg
```

> Simple Grep

```
[root@server ~]$ cat TextFile1.txt | grep "ORA-"
aby ORA-3120: unable to xx
sxyy ORA-3120: unable to aa
ytxy ORA-3120: unable to bb
y41y ORA-3120: unable to dd
yanby ORA-3120: unable to ff
y124gby ORA-3120: unable to gg
```

> Put the results in a variable

```
[root@server ~]$ aa=$(cat TextFile1.txt | grep "ORA-")

[root@server ~]$ echo $aa
aby ORA-3120: unable to xx sxyy ORA-3120: unable to aa ytxy ORA-3120: unable to bb y41y ORA-3120: unable to dd yanby ORA-3120: unable to ff y124gby ORA-3120: unable to gg
```

Desired result:

[root@server ~]$ echo $aa

**\\n** aby ORA-3120: unable to xx **\\n** sxyy ORA-3120: unable to aa **\\n** ytxy ORA-3120: unable to bb **\\n** y41y ORA-3120: unable to dd **\\n** yanby ORA-3120: unable to ff **\\n** y124gby ORA-3120: unable to gg **\\n**

Thank you in advance for the help and hints

Comment: Try using double quotes, `echo "$aa"`

Comment: Why are you storing output in `aa` variable?

Comment: In bash, `"${aa//$'\n'/\\\\n}"`

Comment: @anubhava that variable will be taken by another step of the script to be passed to another program which requires it like that

Comment: @Shawn thank you for the hint, it certainly is a step in the right direction.
But at the moment it doesn't show all the lines that were identified. It kinda cuts them in the middle.
Will try to debug it in the morning when I'm not exhausted.

[root@server]# echo "${aa//$'\n'/\\\\n}"
\\ny124gby ORA-3120: unable to ggaby ORA-3120: unable to xx
[root@server]# echo "${aa//$'\n'/ \\\\n }"
 \\n y124gby ORA-3120: unable to ggaby ORA-3120: unable to xx

Comment: Trying to interpret that comment is an exercise in futility, but a common cause of wierd output is working with a file with Windows style CRLF line endings in an OS that expects LF line endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here are two:

Piping `grep`'s output to `sed`:

```
aa=$(echo " \\\n"; grep "ORA-" TextFile1.txt | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1 \\\\n/')
```

Output:

```
$ aa=$(echo " \\\n"; grep "ORA-" TextFile1.txt | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1 \\\\n/')
$ echo $aa
\\n aby ORA-3120: unable to xx \\n sxyy ORA-3120: unable to aa \\n ytxy ORA-3120: unable to bb \\n y41y ORA-3120: unable to dd \\n yanby ORA-3120: unable to ff \\n y124gby ORA-3120: unable to gg \\n
$
```

Piping `grep`'s output to awk:

```
aa=$(echo " \\\n"; grep "ORA-" TextFile1.txt | awk '{print $0 " \\\\n"}')
```

Output:

```
$ aa=$(echo " \\\n"; grep "ORA-" TextFile1.txt | awk '{print $0 " \\\\n"}')
$ echo $aa
\\n aby ORA-3120: unable to xx \\n sxyy ORA-3120: unable to aa \\n ytxy ORA-3120: unable to bb \\n y41y ORA-3120: unable to dd \\n yanby ORA-3120: unable to ff \\n y124gby ORA-3120: unable to gg \\n
```

Comment: Hi, those are some nice piece of codes, but I am encountering a weird effect. The result I get ( regardless of commands run ) is:

Comment: \\n y124gby ORA-3120: unable to gg \\n

Comment: instead of getting your results which is the one desired I get a partial one. Even if I redirect the output to a file ( in case the terminal displays it wrongly ) it's still the same

Comment: Hi @PancakeSlapper, make sure you're using bash by typing `ps`. Then, break the problem into small parts to see what's not working as expected. First, type `grep "ORA-" TextFile1.txt`, and make sure you get all lines in the file. Then,type only this: `grep "ORA-" TextFile1.txt | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1 \\\\n/'`, and make sure all lines now end with `\\n`, and so on. Let me know what command produces the unexpected output. Also, copy and paste from my response to avoid typos.

Comment: Hi Luis, I am running on bash, and the commands work as expected as they are. When adding the result to a variable for whatever reason everything is dropped except the last line.  Have any ideas on why is happening this ? I have never encountered it

Comment: Try using a "back-quote", `\`` , instead of dollar sign and parentheses, `$()` , for the evaluation: `aa=\` echo " \\\n"; grep "ORA-" TextFile1.txt | awk '{print $0 " \\\\n"}'\` ` . If that doesn't work, verify that you can still get all of the lines with `aa=$(cat TextFile1.txt | grep "ORA-")` . I think that was working for you already.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Will try to work out the last part in displaying it

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to use awk:

```
aa=$(cat TextFile1.txt | grep "ORA-"| awk '{print $0 "\\n"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see with `echo "$aa"` (using double quotes avoiding bash to eat the newlines), every line is already ending with a newline.
When you are sure you don't want the double quotes, just add at the end of each line:

```
aa=$(cat TextFile1.txt | grep "ORA-" | sed 's/$/\\\\n/')
```